# Python - json loads request parameter

Tags: python, json

I'm passing a json in my request data body as follow:-

```
curl --data "data={"applist":{"ads":{"ad":[{"adsid":1,"view_points":25,"view_type":"full","comment":"Success"}]}}}" POSTURL
```

Upon json loads, it throws an error:-

```
data = request.form
print json.loads(str(data.get('data'))) # throws an error
```

Upon printing `data.get('data')`, I get `{applist:{ads:{ad:[{adsid:1,view_points:25,view_type:full,comment:Success}]}}}` which is incorrect json, since double quotes(`""`) are missing. **How do I json load it?**

Comment: Are you using Flask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with your original post request via curl.  You are surrounding the post data with double quotes, but also using double quotes in the post body.  Easiest fix is to surround the post body with single quotes:

```
curl --data 'data={"applist":{"ads":{"ad":[{"adsid":1,"view_points":25,"view_type":"full","comment":"Success"}]}}}' POSTURL
```

Comment: Oopss... Blunder it was. Thanks :) :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you are using Flask, you should use `request.json` to get the already parsed json. To do so, you need to set the content type in your curl request:

`-H "content-type: application/json"`

Second, your data is not valid json. Use this one instead:

```
--data='{"applist":{"ads":{"ad":[{"adsid":1,"view_points":25,"view_type":"full","comment":"Success"}]}}}'
```